# Monero wallet stuck synchronising and I don't understand the "unstuck" guide: please clarify

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

As stated my wallet on windows is stuck with 39179 blocks remaining. I am trying to follow this guide [My blockchain is stuck, how do I "unstuck" it?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it?newreg=8e8735d098fc4da4bfa1ba929b36dfe0)
but the steps are not clear to me.

I have deleted the p2pstate.bin file as per the guide. However the next step does not seem to work and maybe I am doing something wrong.

> If you are using the GUI, simply add --block-sync-size 20 as daemon
>   startup flag. You can do this on the Settings page of the GUI.

I have done this and it says it is synchronising but is still stuck.

the Daemon log is as follows

> 2017-11-09 13:38:48.530   8832    INFO
>     global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories:
>   *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
>   Height: 1400001/1400001 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash
>   259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 7(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 3m 31s
>
> 2017-11-09 13:39:24.029   424 INFO
>     global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories:
>   *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
>   Height: 1400001/1400001 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash
>   259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 7(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 4m 7s
>
> 2017-11-09 13:42:39.564   6840    INFO
>     global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories:
>   *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
>   Height: 1400001/1400001 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash
>   259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 7m 22s
>
> 2017-11-09 13:42:58.939   680 INFO
>     global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories:
>   *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
>   Height: 1400001/1400001 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash
>   259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 7(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 7m 41s
>
> 2017-11-09 13:57:53.165   11424   INFO
>     global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories:
>   *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
>   Height: 1400001/1439180 (97.3%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash
>   259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 22m 36s

I subsequently closed and restarted the wallet and now the Daemon wont even start. So I think I made a mistake or this guide was incomplete and messed up my wallet. Should I restore the file I deleted. Please help, thanks.

EDIT: I want to add that I suspect it could be that i need a new version of the wallet. But I dont know which version i have and it doesnt show it on the wallet. I did download from the site, but now it appears that i have two wallets. If i download the wallet from the site again does it automatically update the wallet i have or do ineed to delete the old wallet. I dont see any options to update the wallet on the GUI interface. The new wallet is confusing becasue you just down load dosens of files and how can i know which one is the actual wallet?

Comment: have started new wallet and the same problem. the daeom wont even start now. so by folowoing the guide i have made it worse

Comment: Did you follow this guide for upgrading? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-1-0. If so, try restarting the GUI + daemon.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck on height 1400001, it's very likely you're using an old version which doesn't know about the new fork consensus rules, so fails to see the new blocks as valid. You need to update your wallet to 0.11.1.0 (0.11.0.0 would also work, but has a few sync bugs, so switching to 0.11.1.0 directly is best). Just replace the binaries with the new ones, or pull from git and build, that's all you need to do. After restarting monerod and wallet to use the new code, it should start syncing again till the end.