# Monero wallet stuck synchronising at 39680 using windows

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet-recovery

One time for less than an hour, the "Blocks Remaining" were actively counting-down. I have restarted both the daemon and the GUI Wallet several times. I have also left them both up and running for more than 24 hours multiple times.  I sent Monero to the Wallet, but it shows 0.00 balance.

2017-11-10 07:55:58.208 9176    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-11-10 07:55:59.214 9176    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:94   Error: Couldn't connect to daemon
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon

2017-11-10 07:56:18.876 9208    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-11-10 07:56:19.882 9208    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:94   Error: Couldn't connect to daemon
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon

2017-11-10 07:56:21.915 3976    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1400001 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 4s

2017-11-10 08:05:56.439 9444    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1439681 (97.2%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 9m 35s

Answer (score 4):

If you're stuck on height 1400001, it's very likely you're using an old version which doesn't know about the new fork consensus rules, so fails to see the new blocks as valid. You need to update your wallet to 0.11.1.0 (0.11.0.0 would also work, but has a few sync bugs, so switching to 0.11.1.0 directly is best). Just replace the binaries with the new ones, or pull from git and build, that's all you need to do. After restarting monerod and wallet to use the new code, it should start syncing again till the end.

Comment: To add, specific upgrading steps can be found here: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-1-0. This guide is applicable to upgrading from an older version to v0.11.1.0 as well.

Comment: i'll try now to update the wallet.. can you please tell me how to replace the binaries with the new ones?

Comment: Just follow the post I linked -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-1-0

Comment: Something like: cp /path/to/new/one /path/to/existing/one (or mv)