# Can't connect to daemon in monero GUI

Tags: daemon

When I try to connect I get "Please check your wallet and daemon log for errors. You can also try to start monerod manually."

From bitmonero log... (below)

*:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2018-05-07 21:36:09.033   0x7fffc70cd3c0    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Suggestions very gratefully received! Many thanks

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Also, have you looked at that ^ guide already?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me... macOS sierra 10.12.6

Yes I have been trying to follow your guides rather than ask repeat questions! I am thinking at this stage that it might be best to resync and start afresh. 
Another additional issue was that I was waiting for a transaction from binance that never came through to the wallet. I was trying to fix that problem when it crashed and I now have the daemon issue too.

Comment: I checked https://xmr.llcoins.net and got the msg “Your private key is invalid. Please check it and try again.”
To my relief this website - https://xmrchain.net - does confirm my transaction, why the difference??

Comment: A few questions first. 1. Did you upgrade to GUI v0.12 before or after April 6? 2. What exactly crashed? Did your PC crash whilst the GUI was syncing? 3. Did you send funds to your "main" address (the one starting with a 4) or to one of your subaddresses (the ones starting with an 8)?

Comment: 1. I was sure I had downloaded GUI after April 6, however looking in my download folder it says the app was created/modified 3 April 2018 at 12:45, could I have downloaded an older version after April 6?
2. The macbook crashed, freezing for an extended period and with force quit not an option I held down the power button and reloaded. The GUI may well have been syncing at the time, it had connected and daemon synced, but frequently needed to re-sync and re-connect whenever I had GUI open 
3. main address

Comment: If your Macbook crashed whilst the GUI your blockchain is, most likely, corrupt. Try these steps: 1. Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI. | 2. Enter `node.moneroworld.com` in box 7 (see -> https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/media/black_settings.png). | 3. Enter `18089` in box 8 (see -> https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/media/black_settings.png). | 4. Click in another (empty) box (on the `Settings` page) to ensure your settings are properly saved.| 5. Exit the GUI and make sure to stop the daemon as well. [1/2]

Comment: 6. Delete `data.mdb` from `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` or `~/.bitmonero` (Linux and Mac OS X) | 7. Restart the GUI (+ daemon). | 8. If the GUI feels laggy / buggy for you, apply this guide -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6651/my-gui-feels-buggy-freezes-all-the-time | If you need any further assistance or incur any issues, please let me know. [2/2]

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience, I followed your steps and wallet and daemon both now synced, but still no balance or history of any transactions... 
As I mentioned, I checked xmr.llcoins.net and got the msg “Your private key is invalid. Please check it and try again.” 
xmrchain.net however, does confirm my transaction, which is confusing me

Comment: What's the `Wallet creation height` (on the `Settings` page of the GUI under `Debug info`)?

Comment: Can you change that to `1350000` and let the wallet refresh?

Comment: Just to check before I do that I got the following message...

"Are you sure you want to rebuild the wallet cache?
The following information will be deleted
- Recipient addresses
- Tx keys
- Tx descriptions

The old wallet cache file will be renamed and can be restored later.

Comment: i.e. should I refresh the wallet and, worst case scenario, the funds don't appear, would I still be able to prove the transactions had occurred from my seed alone?

Comment: "The old wallet cache file will be renamed and can be restored later" - your old private tx keys (to prove you sent funds) will be in that file. Note that you cannot retrieve the private tx keys by restoring from the 25 word mnemonic seed.

Comment: OK thanks I have now changed the wallet creation height to 1350000, and reloaded, sadly the balance is still 0, with no history of any transactions.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right wallet open? You can check the wallet name on the `Settings` page of the GUI under `Debug info`.

Comment: Sorted! I had opened a second wallet, and your recent changes applied to that have worked...Big relief and thanks again for all your help