# Can the Trezor Model T wallet store both Monero and Bitcoin at the same time?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, bitcoin, trezor

I just bought a Trezor Model T last month to store my Bitcoins, and now I am interested in buying some Moneros, too. But before I do that, I need to know whether I can store both at once on my Model T wallet. If I try to install the Monero GUI using the 'Create a new wallet from hardware' option, will that somehow overwrite my Bitcoins? Will I still be able to see/access both my Bitcoins and Moneros once I have the Monero GUI set up? Are there any other related issues or hazards I should be aware of? Thanks in advance for your help ... DS

Answer (score 2):

You can safely use and store Bitcoin and Monero simultaneously with your Trezor model T device.

> If I try to install the Monero GUI using the 'Create a new wallet from hardware' option, will that somehow overwrite my Bitcoins?

No. The Trezor Model T, upon initializing the device, essentially provides a 'master' mnemonic seed that is valid for both Monero and Bitcoin.

> Will I still be able to see/access both my Bitcoins and Moneros once I have the Monero GUI set up?

Yes. Setting up the Monero GUI in conjunction with the Trezor Model T will not affect your Bitcoin (or any other coin for that matter) holdings on the Trezor device.

> Are there any other related issues or hazards I should be aware of?

It is advised to diligently read the guide:

[How do I generate a Trezor Monero wallet with the GUI (monero-wallet-gui)?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11437/how-do-i-generate-a-trezor-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui)

And evidently, it is imperative to properly and safely back up your Trezor mnemonic seed.

Comment: Not sure if I should start a new thread, but perhaps you can answer this question too: if install the Monero GUI on a second computer of mine as well, will that cause any problems with the Trezor wallet? Can I still use the 'Create a new wallet from hardware' option a second time when installing the GUI on the new computer?

Comment: Yes, you can simply replicate the Trezor Monero wallet on the second system.