# GUI Beta 2 Error Message (sync stuck and unable to send funds)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, error-log

I'm using Monero GUI Beta 2, Windows 10, and sent XMR to an exchange. I have been waiting for the blocks to synchronize for two days. 
I think I have an error code. Please advise, I appreciate any help.

Payment ID: 139673d445414546a29fcfebe237258469f71599a5964938a381471e18edf164

-DM

DAEMON LOG:

2017-12-13 21:00:01.728 6240    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1464255 (95.6%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 5(out)+6(in) connections, uptime 0d 2h 31m 4s

2017-12-13 21:19:45.526 668 INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1464262 (95.6%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 8(out)+8(in) connections, uptime 0d 2h 50m 48s

2017-12-13 21:24:35.590 2716    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1464264 (95.6%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 7(out)+3(in) connections, uptime 0d 2h 55m 38s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an outdated version and therefore you won't be able to complete the initial sync nor send funds. You have to upgrade first using this guide:

[How do I upgrade my software to v0.11.1.0?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-1-0)

This guide is applicable to upgrading from Beta 2 (v0.10.3.1) to v0.11.1.0 directly too.

Thereafter, use this guide to solve your pending transaction issue:

[Transaction stuck as "pending" in the GUI](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/transaction-stuck-as-pending-in-the-gui)