# Ubuntu 16.04 : Monero wallet stopped working

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Wanted to load monero wallet but it has stopped working. 
monero-gui-0.11.0.0

Getting these messages in console:

```
app startd
qml: check next false
qml: Checking seed
qml: check next false
qml: check next false
qml: log level changed:  0
qml: transfer page loaded
qml: PrivacyLevel changed:0
qml: mixin count: 4
qml: qrScannerEnabled disabled
qml: setting demo token
qml: initializing..
setLanguage   "en"
qml: transfer page loaded
qml: PrivacyLevel changed:0
qml: mixin count: 4
qml: opening wallet at:  path/monero.dat , testnet:  false
Wallet* WalletManager::openWallet(const QString&, const QString&, bool): opening wallet at path/monero.dat, testnet = 0 
Checking for updates
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: it's monero-gui-0.11.0.0

Comment: Did v0.11.0.0 work before?

Comment: yes it worked before as a matter of fact I openend it up yesterday. 
It had been a while since I opened it and it was syncing the chain. 
I don't think it was complete until I had to go to bed so I shut down the computer. I do think I just closed the wallet correctly. As I always do.

Weird

Comment: Could be that one of your drivers is toast or was upgraded incorrectly. Could you check whether the v0.11.1.0 makes any difference? Upgrade: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-1-0

Answer (score 1):

After restarting my laptop this issue has gone away. 
I suppose it was a driver that didn't boot up correctly or something.

I'm glad it works again
I'll download and use the new wallet when my blockchain has synced